# Resource leak over String Scanner java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, resource-leak

In vscode I get a warning saying that Scanner has a resource leak for scanning over a String, but String doesn't need to be closed, so why does vscode give me a warning and how can I get rid of it?  I don't want to close the Scanner because that is not necessary.  Here is some example code that gives the warning

```java
new Scanner("somthing to split")
            .useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[ ,\n]"))
            .forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

Gives
`Resource leak: '<unassigned Closeable value>' is not closed at this location`

Comment: @AlexR but won't this make it run slower? I'm trying to not close it because it is unnecessary but I don't want this warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSCode does not care what resource your `Scanner` is tied to. It does not check whether you actually *should* close it or not.

Either **suppress the warning**, by adding `@SuppressWarnings("resource")` or **close** the scanner properly using [try-with-resources syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(...)) {
    ...
} // auto-closed here
```

Not all warnings are actually *correct*, there are false positives as well and it is totally okay to suppress a warning in such a case. You might want to add a comment to explain *why* though.

Another related example are scanners tied to `System.in`, they should not be closed either.

---

> but won't this make it run slower? I'm trying to not close it because it is unnecessary but I don't want this warning

No, not really. And even if, we would be talking about a few nanoseconds here. Dont try to micro-optimize something that does not have to be optimized at all. If you think you have a speed issue, profile your application and then you will notice that your offender is something completely different anyways.

Comment: The suppress warnings is exactly what I wanted, thank you

Comment: @ColbyQuinn Sometimes, there are things better than ***thank you***, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers