# Although I close my Scanner class at the end of the code as sc.close(); but still it shows the error as source leakage : sc was never closed. Help me

Tags: java

When I try to compile, it runs but it highlights scanner object sc in yellow colour line prompting that sc was never closed.
It disappears only when I close my Scanner class immediately after I initialise it. But then my user input functionality is disrupted.

I don't want to use try catch at this point. Because earlier codes didn't raise this issue.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Array{
 public static void main (String args[]);{


    int a[]=new int[5];

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers:");

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){

        a[]=sc.nextInt();

    }

    System.out.println("You entered:");

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){

      System.out.println(a[i]);

    }

    sc.close();

   }


}
```

This problem is faced in vs code.

Comment: Considering specifying which IDE your using.

Comment: I guess that really depends on the config of your IDE. I just pasted your code to my eclipse. No warnings there (but compilation errors, as your code is not correct at the a[] = sc.nextInt() call as well as ther is a semicolon missing at the sc.close() line. But other than that no warnings about sc never being closed. I know you mentioned you don't want to use try catch here, but honestly it is the only way to assure sc being closed imho.

Comment: A scanner opened with `System.in` should not be closed manually.  The warning should just be ignored or turned off.  If you close the scanner, you also are closing the underlying stream which is already handled automatically without you intervening. For example, if you try to then open a new `Scanner` on `System.in` again, it will just not work because you closed `System.in`

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse IDE, you can go to **Window>Preferences>Java>Compiler>Errors/Warning** and search out `resource leak`, the first option should be `Resource leak:` which you can change from *warning* to *ignore*. Apply changes and Close. This should remove the yellow underline and the error you used to see completely. Hopefully this helps!

P.S Remember that you **might** want to turn it back on incase you are working with other InputStreams and find this as a useful reminder.

Comment: @Gargi Your question presumes 'this warning is sensible'. __Therein lies your problem__. The warning is __flat out incorrect__, your tooling is messing up here. You __do not__ close resources unless __you are responsible for them__. `new X()` is one way to be responsible. Any method that spells it out (such as `Files.newInputStream` or `socket.getOutputStream()`) in its docs also easy. But `System.in` is explicitly NOT your responsibility, and you must explicitly NOT close things you shouldn't be closing. The IDE is confused. Tell your IDE to ignore the warning. This answer tells you how.

Comment: In defense of eclipse and to expand a bit: Most tools get this wrong because the way filterstreams interact is very complicated, and thus hard for static code tools to figure it out. There is no standard for determining if a method that returns a resource also confers responsibility, so most tools are forced to assume they always do. `System.in` __does not__. The only real hope is for a tool to hardcode the notion of filterstreams _and_ to hardcode the notion of `System.in` - the expression- does not convey transfer of responsibility. Hence: Do not use auto-mark 'unclosed resource' tools.

Comment: And one last insight: [A] if you close a filter stream (which is a thing that wraps around another thing - Scanner itself isn't a resource, Scanner wraps around one. `System.in` in this case), closes the underlying thing, and [B] what eclipse wants you to do (but don't - that is incorrect) is: `try (Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)) { .... }`. The `close()` you aren't calling is if the code `return;`s or exits via throwing some exception before you ever get to that `close()` call you wrote.

Comment: Please read all of @rzwitserloot comments. You may find them helpful in understanding why you should ignore this error!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer but you're using VSCode. As of now I haven't found a way to completely ignore this warning (I will update you as soon as I do :>) but for now you could use `@SuppressWarnings("resource")` annotation above your Scanner declaration or use a try-with-resources with the following syntax:-

```
try(Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in)) {
   // All the code that requires the scanner
}
```

Got this from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66664246/21252090)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few syntax errors within your code.

The *main* method has a semi-colon at the end, remove this.

```java
public static void main (String args[]);{
```

And, the *a* array assignment has empty brackets.

```java
a[]=sc.nextInt();
```

Change this to,

```java
a[i]=sc.nextInt();
```

Here is an example input and output.

```
Enter 5 numbers:
1 2 3 4 5
You entered:
1
2
3
4
5
```

Here is the *Java* tutorial on *methods*.

- *[Defining Methods (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Classes and Objects)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)*

And, here is one on *arrays*.

- *[Arrays (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)*